# Getting results from Spark (scala) and pass it to another process

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In general, how to extract results from a spark job without going output files?

Let say, I have a scala program which creates a spark launcher job.

I can wrap this spark job with `Futures`. Once the spark job is finished, how can I get the results back? (1 way I did it before is making the spark job writing the results to a file, then the external scala program read the file. <- I want to avoid this strategy)

Comment: Better would be to develop a pipeline where Spark jobs finishes and then another jobs starts....if thats not favorable way then have Spark job write output to a socket or MQ and have your another program listening to that Queue.

Comment: Carson - if the above strategy works, then i can out that as an answer and if not then let me know the challenge do you see in the approach.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit, may you elaborate a bit more on the socket/MQ strategy? I would like to explore that direction further.

I like your idea having a streaming strategy (rather than the file based strategy)

Comment: You can for example use `foreach` / `foreachPartition` or develop your own data source writer / output format. Still, passing data through files adds explicit recovery point a reduces an effort required to handle data exchange failures. If you add in-memory file system an overhead should be minimal.

Comment: @zero323, thanks for pointing out explicit recovery point + in memory file system. This is really good stuff. I didn't think of that at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For small resultset, using RDD.collect() to return all the elements of the dataset as an array at the driver program.

```
def collect(): Array[T]
```

then
Print to standard output as pipeline input, for example RDD.collect().foreach(print_to_stout)

or as suggested by Sumit, write each element to external messaging systems via below API:

```
def foreach(f: (T) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```